# How I can optimize this where conditions in Yii2 philosophy

Tags: php, yii2

I have this code and want optimize where condition write in example. How can I do this:

How rewrite this with another method, so that the result remains the same:

```
->where(
    "(b.updated_at is null 
        OR u.updated_at > b.updated_at 
        OR i.updated_at > b.updated_at
    ) AND (
        u.last_name <> ''
        OR u.first_name <> ''
    ) AND (
        u.updated_at > :seconds 
        OR i.updated_at > :seconds
    )",
    ['seconds' => $seconds]
)
```

Comment: what do you mean by *optimize where condition* and why do you want to change this query ?

Comment: rewrite this with another method, so that the result remains the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split this into array syntax:

```
->where(
    [
        'AND',
        [
            'OR',
            'b.updated_at is null',
            'u.updated_at > b.updated_at',
            'i.updated_at > b.updated_at',
        ],
        [
            'OR',
            "u.last_name <> ''",
            "u.first_name <> ''",
        ],
        [
            'OR',
            'u.updated_at > :seconds',
            'i.updated_at > :seconds',
        ],
    ],
    ['seconds' => $seconds]
)
```

But this will not make it more efficient nor more readable. So unless you want to do some further processing on this condition (it should be easier to do this on array than on string), it may be better to leave this condition as string.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you call 'optimize' here, but you can also try to chain calls.

IMHO, it makes the query more readable - even if it's the same generated SQL in the end  :

```
        ->where("b.updated_at is null OR u.updated_at > b.updated_at OR i.updated_at > b.updated_at")
        ->andWhere("u.last_name <> '' OR u.first_name <> ''")
        ->andWhere("u.updated_at > :seconds OR i.updated_at > :seconds", ['seconds' => $seconds])->all();
```